# Ubuntu freezes randomly without nomodeset

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu, nomodeset

My ubuntu 18.04 freezes soon after booting up and i have to hard reboot it to fix it. It works fine with nomodeset in grub. I cannot find any work arounds for this. My system is running on AMD A9 and radeon R5 integrated graphics. How to install graphic drivers for this?